# Does anyone know what is wrong my Broadcast Receiver running in a Service?

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to run this `BroadcastReceiver` in a `Service`.

I register it in `onStartCommand`:

```
import android.app.Service
import android.content.*
import android.os.IBinder
import android.util.Log
import java.util.*


class CopyService : Service() {
    private lateinit var mPasteReceiver: PasteReceiver
    private val TAG = "COPYSERVICE"

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PASTE)
        mPasteReceiver = PasteReceiver()
        registerReceiver(mPasteReceiver, intentFilter)
        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(mPasteReceiver)
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? = null

    inner class PasteReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Paste received.")
        }
    }
}
```

It does not work! :(

I should specify I am trying to get a clipboard paste event.

Comment: Make sure your Service class onStartCommand method is called.

Comment: I successfully got a Log message from it, so I know it is called :/

Comment: Can you please share the service code as well

Comment: I have shared the class on the main post.

Comment: Have you registered your broadcast receiver in manifest?

Comment: That is not necessary because I do it dynamically, right?